# Error: Cannot find module 'concat-map' when i try to run command line npm like "npm init"

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-publish

when i try to publish package to npm, i got the following error, happens when i run npm commands like "npm init", "npm publish", etc., how to fix it?

$ npm init
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module 'concat-map'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\bim2016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\glob\node_modules\brace-expansion\index.js

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can do to remove this error message.

---

Firstly, you can simply try and install everything again by simply running the command below in a directory where a `package.json` file is present.

```
$ npm install
```

---

Secondly, make sure that the package supports either `require()` or `import`.

Normally, it would have it on the homepage of the `npm` website.

If you find out that the module uses `require()`, use the following steps.

1. Remove the following from `package.json`.

   ```json
   {
     "type": "module"
   }
   ```
2. Replace the `import` statement with the below in your JavaScript code.

   ```js
   const concatMap = require("concat-map");
   ```

If you realise it needs the `import` statement, follow these steps.

1. Add the following in `package.json`.

   ```json
   {
     "type": "module"
   }
   ```
2. Replace the `require()` function with the `import` statement in your JavaScript code.

   ```js
   import concatMap from "concat-map";
   ```

---

Thirdly, if you are publishing to `npm`, make sure that the package is listed in the `dependencies` section of `package.json`.

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "concat-map": "^0.0.1"
  }
}
```

<sub>*Note: This version was the current version of the package at the time of writing.*</sub>

---

Fourthly, you can reinstall Node.js and npm.

1. Install and run the LTS installer from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/). It will overwrite the already-present version.

This should fix the issue if the problem based on a bug fixed in later versions.

---

These are some steps you can take to make sure that `concat-map` is working correctly, and to rid the error.

Comment: thanks Arnav, looks like something wrong w/ my npm or even nodejs, i tried update npm using "npm update -g npm", same error message, in fact, any npm command will result in exactly the same error message, do i have to uninstall npm and even nodejs then reinstall both? if so then how to do it properly?

Comment: thanks again Arnav, i reinstalled nodejs and seems OK now, but when i use "npm publish" to publish my testing package, below error occurs, how to fix it?
npm ERR! code E426
npm ERR! 426 Upgrade Required - PUT http://registry.npmjs.org/@bim2016%2fshadowizard

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bim2016\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-27T09_13_50_647Z-debug-0.log

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I've followed the link and it comes with a 404.

Comment: npm ERR! code E426
npm ERR! 426 Upgrade Required - PUT http://registry.npmjs.org/shadowizard
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bim2016\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-27T09_31_36_911Z-debug-0.log

Comment: thanks Arnav, i've updated the link, how to upgrade? again, very appreciated for your help!

Comment: extra info right before error message:
npm notice Publishing to http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm ERR! code E426

Comment: I think you should try following the link to the GitHub Blog in your answer. It has some useful information that might help solve the issue you're having. If it helps, I'll update my answer. _(I'm going offline now, so I won't be able to help you for a few hours (nighttime at my area). I'll see to you in the morning (at my area), which will be about 10-12 hours.)_ I'm glad I could help!

Comment: sure Arnav, good night. i looked in that github link and tried but in vain, my nodejs version is v16.15.0, upgrade npm to v7, disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 at Internet Option, for unknown reason, i cannot type in Password at command line, see below:                        $ npm adduser
npm WARN config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead.
npm WARN config init.license Use `--init-license` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.email Use `--init-author-email` instead.              
Username: bim2016
Password: